# Thunderbird spam filter image-only content

Tags: spam, thunderbird, spamassassin

I'm finding that spam messages which are just images are getting past both my server's Spam Assassin and Thunderbird's filtering.   (Not remote images - I block those – but attachments with zero message body text).

I would like to have a filtering rule to mark them as spam and delete.

Barring that I would like to be able to not load a preview of image attachments in the message display, but I haven't been able to find such a setting.  I'm sure I've seen that in other email apps, is that really not available in Thunderbird?

Thx in advance
-Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching, I see that many email clients don't have an "empty body" trigger for spam filtering, however a work around is to filter msgs to the trash on the conditions:

```
 body does-not-contain  'a'   AND
 body does-not-contain  'e'   AND 
 body does-not-contain  'i'   ...
```

…etc, so any (English at least) body is sure to have a few vowels, and get delivered, yet blank-body msgs with a only a pic attached get trashed.

Hope this helps someone else looking to filter email messages with blank body.

-R